# AngularJS/MeteorJS Folder Structure

Tags: angularjs, meteor

So I developed an application and I ended up using the default folder structure which is the following :

Name of application is Calorie Counter

```
CalorieCounter.css
CalorieCounter.html
CalorieCounter.js
index.ng.html
```

And now that my code is getting longer, I've realized that I should've organized it with better folder organization. I want to structure it better but I'm a little lost on how to exactly start.

Here's the github : https://github.com/jalapagos/SimpleCalorieCounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly used folder structure while **angular application Development**

```
app/
----- controllers/
---------- mainController.js
---------- otherController.js
----- directives/
---------- mainDirective.js
---------- otherDirective.js
----- services/
---------- userService.js
---------- itemService.js
----- js/
---------- bootstrap.js
---------- jquery.js
----- app.js
views/
----- mainView.html
----- otherView.html
----- index.html
```

Comment: That's only useful for small app or getting start. Not fit for scalable app. 
Highly recommend don't use it if you want expand more.

Answer (score -1):

```
-App
--css
--js
--img
--templates
--index.html
```

Answer (score -1):

You implement feature based hierarchy.

[image: you check this image]

[Visit this GURU link](http://www.johnpapa.net/structuring-an-angular-project/)